# Compare objects from two models in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models PriceActual and PriceBenchmark having fields date and price.

I want to compare the actual prices with the benchmark prices.

I'm not interested in benchmark prices with dates which is not present in the actual prices. So if PriceActual only has objects from the last week, I only want to query objects from PriceBenchmark also within the last week.

I guess it's something like

```
actual = PriceActual.objects.all()
benchmark = PriceActual.objects.filter(date__in=actual)
```

## Edit

The models are really simple

```
class PriceActual(models.Model):
    date = DateField()
    price = DecimalField()

class PriceBenchmark(models.Model):
    date = DateField()
    price = DecimalField()
```

Comment: Can you show us the models?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient...but you could always create a list of dates:

```
actual = PriceActual.objects.all()
actual_dates = [x.date for x in actual]
benchmark = PriceActual.objects.filter(date__in=actual_dates)
```

Comment: It might work but if I'm going to use it in a flot.js chart, wont it be sufficient to just find the start and end date? I know that I said my question that I want those objects with same dates as in PriceActual but I guess it doesn't matter that PriceBenchmark returns more objects as long as they are within a range of dates